# why In C all executable code is contained within functions

Tags: c, function, optimization

Why In C all executable code is contained within functions ?

Is this for optimization purposes ?

if so how can it optimize a C program ?

if not why **dennis ritchie** designed the language this way

And it will be good if someone can **answer/comment** a good reference/link about this for me to go through if available.

i need these important points explained:

"**1) Why in C all executable code is contained within functions if this is for the puposes of optimization. how it helps with optimizing a C program**"

"**if optimization is not the purpose why dennis ritchie wanted to design the C language like this**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this for optimization purposes ?

No.

> If not why Dennis Ritchie designed the language this way:

Because this is how (most) mainstream high level programming languages designed *before* C were designed to worked.  (The main exceptions to this were COBOL, BASIC and RPG.)

As all influentual programming language designers do, Dennis Ritchie adopted (and adapted) ideas that worked well in earlier languages, and discarded ideas that didn't.  The "works well" is determined by the collective experience of the people who developed the language compilers, and the thousands or millions of programmers used the languages to write working programs.